# Working with large arrays on google colab Python

Tags: arrays, numpy, ram, large-data, diskspace

I want to create an array with numpy.zeros of the size 100k x 100k in google colab. The RAM is getting crashed whenever I try to do this operation. Is there any way that I can use the disk space and create one? Also, I have to perform operations on it by adding values to it.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((100000,100000))
arr
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.zeros()` is trying to allocate 80GB of RAM to fit the 100k x 100k array, which is not available to your instance. You try to use `np.empty()` instead:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.empty((100000,100000))
arr
```

which will give you:

```
 array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Yes, this works only for creating an array. But when I try to perform any operation, the RAM is getting crashed.